# Transparent material appears black (v2.93)

Tags: materials

Transparency doesn't work, and instead of a transparent object there is a black object.

What I do except: a transparent cylinder

The result:

[image]

Material:
[image]

Blender Version 2.93; I also tried out installing other version, but it didn't work

---

I tried this:[image]
but it didn't work. By the way I'm using Cycles.

Also, making a semitransparent cylinder didn't work too:[image]

EDIT: trying changing blend mode from opaque to alpha blend worked. Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you set the Transparency max bounces to zero. Transparency can't happen without at least one bounce.

[image: no bounce demo gif]

The default Transparency bounce is 8 and you most likely don't need a lower value. More often than not, either you let it as is, or you crank it up when you have many transparent items in front of each other that provoke a falloff effect:

[image: falloff demo gif]