# Model Hair and Teeth Not Moving

Tags: rigging, hair, pose-mode

I am very new to blender. I imported a model from xnalara as an obj. file so that I could use it in blender. After rigging it, I noticed that the hair and teeth do not follow the head bone when I pose it. The only vertex groups I have are for my bones. I do not see the hair and teeth listed in the collection as separate meshes. The entire body, including hair and teeth, are showing as one mesh, yet when I pose the head, the hair and teeth remain fixed in place. How do I make the hair and teeth move with the head?

I also noticed that this model's hair and eyelashes look like pictures of hair on a sheet of black paper. Is there a way to fix that?

Would greatly appreciate any help or links to a hair tutorial. Thank you!

[image: model posed in object mode]

[image: model posed in edit mode]

Comment: To get rid of the black parts you need to enable *Transparency* in the material settings. Set the render engine to EEVEE to see the options (for viewport & EEVEE). Try *Blend Mode* = *Alpha Hashed* or *Alpha Blend* and make sure *Show Backface* is *not* checked if you want to use *Alpha Blend* (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGdqt.jpg). Also, make sure you use an *Alpha* mask in the shader. For Cycles render, you might have to increase the Max Bounces (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/230578/107598)

Comment: about the not-moving hair and teeth: the meshes are loose, and not connected to the rest of the body. That's ok. But they also got no weights assigned (probably because they are loose parts). That's causing the problem. You need to assign the vertices of the hair and teeth to the head bone's vertex group manually. Here's an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/49388/107598